# How to import special.hermite from scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, python-import, physics, hermite

I'm looking to import a hermite polynomial. When I check the documentation on the scipy website it's available. However, when I try to import it there is `no module found`

Comment: Show the *exact* code that you tried (preferably a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and show the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback).  There is useful information in there.

Comment: Also read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html#scipy-organization, which explains that the SciPy subpackages must be imported explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scipy.special
p = scipy.special.hermite(63)
```

should work.